# VIM functions, variables hints per project

Tags: php, vim, ctags

What solutions are for vim to have better completion with hints?

For example I have class:

```
class Main {
function __construct()
{
    echo "Function loaded...<br>"
}

/* public testIt(int $num, string $var) {{{ */ 
/**
 * testIt
 * 
 * @param int $num 
 * @param string $var 
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function testIt(int $num, string $var)
{
    echo $num . ". " . $var;
}
/* }}} */
}
```

And other file:

```
include("class.php);

$main = new Main();

$main->testIt(
```

And then I type `$main->testIt(` function hint should popup (something like in netbeans).

I know I can achieve it with ctags, but problem is I need only tags which exist in project. For example Im writting `$main->tes` and hint should popup with `testIt()` function hint only.

I know answer probably will be pretty obvious, but it's little bit confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Vim is not an IDE; if you want better completion / IntelliSense, use a (language-specific) IDE instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want project and context aware completion, I leverage the power of an IDE (Eclipse) through Vim (using [eclim](http://eclim.org)). You may find other IDE integrations out there, for example I know Netbeans has extensive Vim support.

This lets me use Vim for what it's good at - editing - and use an IDE for what it's good at - understanding and manipulating my project.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does IDE allow for vim to have scripts? Cause I already tried with phpstorm and it didn't allow vim scripts. Im downloading to test it with both - netbeans and eclipse.

Comment: "IDE" is a generic term for the TYPE of application that Eclipse falls under, an "[Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)". As far as I know, only Vim allows vim scripts, so no: an IDE will never allow Vim script. But eclim is a PLUGIN for the Eclipse IDE and also a plugin for the Vim editor. This allows Vim (the editor, running independently) to communicate with Eclipse (the IDE). The Netbeans integration is similar. The IDE does NOT run vim scripts. The plugins just allow Vim to USE the IDE in addition to Vim's built-in features.

Answer (score 0):

Combine [my Vim Settings](https://github.com/convissor/vim-settings) with [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/) (which you have to [build from source](http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/blog/html/its-alive-universal-ctags-fork-of-exuberant-ctags.htm)), [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html), [Ctags for SVN](https://github.com/convissor/ctags_for_svn).

Then adjust the `ctags` calls Tim Pope's git hooks (from above) to add the `--php-kinds=-v` parameter.

The articles in the [ctags thread of my blog](http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/blog/blog-ctags.htm) have more details and some other vim settings to make coding PHP in vim a lovely experience.